# How to simplify git log to show only certain commits and their merge bases?

Tags: git

For example, if I do:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate master branch dcfadf1
```

I see all commits:

```
* e8599bb (HEAD -> branch) branch5
* 2fe1c92 branch4
| * f083d02 (master) master5
| * d33bf64 master4
|/  
* a286c74 master3
* dcfadf1 master2
* 6f58634 master1
```

However, I'd like to see instead only:

```
* e8599bb (HEAD -> branch) branch5
| * f083d02 (master) master5
|/  
* a286c74 master3
* dcfadf1 master2
```

to better understand how those specific commits are related.

Why each of those commits those should appear:

- `e8599bb` (`branch`), `f083d02` (`master`) and `dcfadf1`: given on the command line
- `a286c74`: merge base (most recent common ancestor) of two of the commits given on the command line (`branch` and `master`).

I can't use `--simplify-by-decoration`, since my actual repo has a lot of branches I don't care about, and furthermore it removes merge bases by default: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/quot-git-log-simplify-by-decoration-quot-but-including-branch-amp-merge-points-td6825766.html

Here is the test repo which corresponds to the above `git log` commands: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-so-46270360

```
git clone https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-so-46270360
cd test-so-46270360
git checkout master
git checkout -
```

Comment: I don't think there is any built in way to simplify like this, but you can use `--no-walk` and explicitly name the commits to view, including the merge base, by adding `$(git merge-base branch master)` to the arguments. But I wonder if this works with `--graph`, perhaps I should try it :-) ... edit: no, it doesn't. I don't think there is a way to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: @torek ah, docs say "Cannot be combined with --graph" :-( But it is a good attempt anyways! If they could be combined, that would be a possible semantic for it.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com - thank you, thank you, thank you.  Your mention of `--simplify-by-decoration` is the answer to the question that _I_ came looking for!!!  Funny that it was easier for me to find my answer in _your_ question than it was for me to find my "answer"!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, `--graph` makes no sense if you intend to see commits not necessarily related to each other. Hence I'd advice you to drop `--graph` and you'll be able to use `--no-walk`.

Here's `git log`'s documentation of `--no-walk` for reference:

> Only show the given commits, but do not traverse their ancestors. This has no effect if a range is specified. If the argument unsorted is given, the commits are shown in the order they were given on the command line. Otherwise (if sorted or no argument was given), the commits are shown in reverse chronological order by commit time. Cannot be combined with --graph.

So for your example, I'd use:

```
git log --oneline --no-walk --decorate master branch dcfadf1
```

Comment: My desired output makes sense... to me :-)